# Suggestions for describing and naming a permutation

Tags: permutations, soft-question

In my research in quantum computing, the permutations of a multiset of non-negative integers are introduced. For example, if I have the multiset
$\{0,0,1,2,2,3\}$
then we get permutations $\{001223, 010223,...\}$. I would like a name for the permutation $001223$, and a general description of it. I named it "the identity permutation" (having consulted Stanley's definition of permutations in Enumerative Combinatorics and seeing that this permutation corresponds to the identity bijection) and described it as "the permutation that never decreases," but my research professor asks for a clearer description.

> Is "identity permutation" a good name? And how would you improve the description?

Comment: Why not the "sorted order"?

Comment: @GregMartin would that be "increasing sorted order"?

Answer (score 1):

It's the unique permutation that lists the numbers in numerical (hence nondecreasing) order. If you need a name for it, perhaps "smallest" would be appropriate, since it is the least number when you think of the integers as determining a number using place value for a large enough base.

For example, $001223$ is the smallest number you can write in base $4$ using those six digits.

Please don't call it the identity. That word has too many meanings already in mathematics. For permutations it means the permutation that moves nothing. In your example $001223$ represents the identity only if you assume that order to start with. So to avoid a circular definition you must describe that order first. That's what my suggestion does.

Comment: Please explain "it is the least number when you think of the integers as determining a number using place value for a large enough base" further, I don't understand it. And can you explain why I shouldn't call it the "identity"?

Comment: @DavidRaveh See my edits.